# Pass a Class as a parameter when creating a new thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

To keep things short, I am trying to pass a Class as a parameter to another method that is owned by a different thread. This is a simplification of my code:

```
Friend Sub SplitFile(ByVal fileSplitterSettings As FileSplitterSettingsObject)
        Dim _threadSplitFile As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() Thread_SplitFile_Start(fileSplitterSettings))          
        _threadSplitFile.Start()
End Sub
```

SplitFile() is being called by Thread 1, which creates Thread 2, passing in an Object that was instantiated in Thread 1 as a parameter for a method that will be run under the context of Thread 2.

However, whenever I try to access **fileSplitterSettingsObject** in the method Thread_SplitFile_Start which is being run under Thread 2, I get an error stating that a different thread owns it.

I know of **Dispatcher.Invoke()** and how to use it to run, read, and change methods and objects of other threads, but I am unsure how to implement this here. I can create a new instance of that class under the context of Thread 2 in Thread_SplitFile_Start, and use Dispatcher.Invoke() for each and every property in Thread_SplitFile_Start in order to copy over values from fileSplitterSettings in Thread 1's context, to a new instance in Thread 2's context, but that seems to be overkill and I'm looking for a simpler alternative.

If there's any additional information needed, I will happily provide it.

Any help or advice would greatly be appreciated!

EDIT:

Since passing primitive types like Integers, Strings, etc work fine, I thought passing in a Structure type would work instead, but this didn't seem to work either.

EDIT:

This is this Class I am working with. It is one I created, so any changes needed for it I can change:

```
Namespace Classes

Friend NotInheritable Class FileSplitterSettingsObject
```

## Region " Enumerations "

```
    Friend Enum FileSavingMode
        ModeTogether = 0
        ModeSeparate = 1
    End Enum
```

## End Region

## Region " Properties "

```
    Private _propertyDeleteOriginalFile As Boolean = False
    Private _propertyUseCustomSuffixes As Boolean = False
    Private _propertyFilenameSuffixes As List(Of ListBoxItem)
    Private _propertySavingMode As FileSavingMode = Nothing

    Friend Property DeleteOriginalFile As Boolean
        Get
            Return _propertyDeleteOriginalFile
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _propertyDeleteOriginalFile = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property UseCustomSuffixes As Boolean
        Get
            Return _propertyUseCustomSuffixes
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _propertyUseCustomSuffixes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property FileNameSuffixes As List(Of ListBoxItem)
        Get
            Return _propertyFilenameSuffixes
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of ListBoxItem))
            _propertyFilenameSuffixes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property SavingMode As FileSavingMode
        Get
            Return _propertySavingMode
        End Get
        Set(value As FileSavingMode)
            _propertySavingMode = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

## End Region

```
End Class
```

End Namespace

My apologies for not clarifying this earlier, but I can access "most" of these properties in Thread 2. The only one I cannot access is **FileNameSuffixes**, which is set like this in Thread 1:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lbSuffixes.Items.Count - 1
        lbSuffixesItemsList.Add(New ListBoxItem With {
                                                         .Content = CType(lbSuffixes.Items(i), ListBoxItem).Content
                                                     })
Next
```

I believe it has something to do with instantiating the ListBoxItems in Thread 1, which is why Thread 2 cannot access them. Basically, I'm needing to pass those items someway to Thread 2, so I can access their properties. I know I could make a list of type String and it would probably work, but it would be nice to know if what I'm trying to do can be done in the future (e.g. for Objects with several properties set at once, don't want create a bunch of custom properties based on primitive types just to pass along information)

Comment: Pass a _class_ or an _instance_? Looks more like the latter.

Comment: Instance of a class declared in Thread 1

Comment: _I get an error stating_ ... Can you paste that error?

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it: refering to fileSplitterSettingsObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After collaborating with @Brian Saunders, I have determined it best to just use a generic string array for passing that troublesome property.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too simple (and I don't have your object to test with), but I think .Invoke with your code would look like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
    Dim _threadSplitFile As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() Thread_SplitFile_Start(fileSplitterSettings))          
        _threadSplitFile.Start()
End Sub)
```

OR this:

```
Dim _threadSplitFile As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() Thread_SplitFile_Start(fileSplitterSettings))          
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
        _threadSplitFile.Start()
End Sub)
```

... depending on where you get the error.

But - you are creating 2 threads which will, in turn, wait for the main thread to execute (because fileSplitterSettings isn't thread-safe).  If I were you, I would think about re-designing.  Maybe:

1. Pass the settings you need in a thread-safe class (eg - one you create).  Even if that's just a facade on top of fileSplitterSettings
2. Create a fileSplitterSettings object WITHIN this thread, and
3. Execute .Start here within the same thread.

Then - you get multi-threading and dont need to mess with the dispatcher.  Again, might be way too simplistic, and I don't know your environment/restrictions.  Hopefully gives you something to play with at least!

Comment: Thanks for the information Brian. I have a question about your first block of code. At the time Thread 2 is created in my project, there is only one thread running, the main one when the program starts. Would calling Dispatcher.Invoke() change anything on how Thread 2 runs, if everything before that point is running under the context of Thread 1 anyways? Also, I edited my original post to include the class, with some additional information.

Comment: See - I think that ListBoxItem is causing your hearburn (because its a goofy UI element, and UI elements are owned by the UI thread, maybe?).  Would it be a gigantic pain to just create your own dictionary for those fileNameSuffix values?  But wait, that wasn't your actual question, was it.... sorry.  OK. I've always thought of .Invoke as a way to "block" Thread2 so Thread1 can act (eg - your UI will "freeze" for that duration).  Ideally, you would freeze the UI for the microseconds it takes to update the ListBoxItem, I suppose. Is that close?

Comment: I had thought that invoking was basically "asking" a specific thread to run a specific method under it's context. That was, Thread 1 could ask Thread 2 to run a method, then go along its merry way. But all aside, FileNameSuffixes doesn't have to be a dictionary. It could be an ItemCollection or an Array of ListBoxItem (all of which don't work).

In short, I'm just looking for a way to pass along a class containing information to another thread. If you know of an easier way to approach this, I'd be glad to hear it out :)

Comment: You have it exactly right, I think (just that you are waiting for that other thread to "answer" before moving on).  There's a [cool post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287142/invoke-is-blocking) on Invoke vs BeginInvoke btw.  On your actual problem (assuming you dont want to use Invoke), try Dictionary, man.  Both ItemCollection and ListBoxItem are UI controls (eg - you are passing a pointer to a windows control, not "data").  So, If your list box is string/string, you can use Dictionary(string, string) instead of ListBoxItem.Content ...

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but only because the Content property of the ListBoxItem is a string. What if I wanted to pass a UI control to extract its properties though? Let's say for example I wanted to pass a UIElement with like 20+ properties I need to read from. Is there a way to pass a UI object at all?

Comment: For WinForms, I ran a quick test this am.  I can pass a UI control to the thread, but I have to access it within an .Invoke to avoid this error.  Because, I assume, the primary UI thread could modify the object properties, and you only have it's lowly pointer in your wimpy class ;-) .... (at least that's how I would write up the docs if I were in charge in Redmond. Could be why nobody's offering me the job.  Well ... one reason among many).  Frustrating though, right??

Comment: One last comment ...  Here is a great article on UI controls and thread safety (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx). It references the relevant .net documentation: "there are [only] four methods on a control that are thread safe: Invoke, BeginInvoke, EndInvoke and CreateGraphics"

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll definitely take a look at that page. I have decided to pass just an array of strings since all I need are the contents of the list items as a string. You mentioned you were able to pass the object in a WinForms project. Do you have a code sample for this, or was it the same format as your example above? Thanks again for your time :)